# How to make a document that can be validated by hand?

Tags: security, language-agnostic

Here's a (simplified) example of my situation.
The user plays a game and gets a high-score of 200 points. I award high-scores with money, i.e. 1€/10 points. The user will print a "receipt" which says he won €20, then he gives it to me, **I make sure the receipt is authentic and has never been used before** and I hand him his prize.
My "issue" is in the bold part, obviously. I should be able to validate the "receipt" by hand, but solutions with other offline methods are welcome too (i.e. small .jar applications for my phone). Also, it must be hard to make fake receipts.

Here's what I thought so far, their pros and their cons.

- **Hashing using common algorithms** i.e. SHA512

  - *Pros*: can easily be validated by mobile devices, has a strong resistance to faking it with higher values (if a context-depending salt is used, i.e. the username).
  - *Cons*: can be used multiple times, cannot be validated by hand.
- **Self-made hash algorithms**

  - *Pros*: can be validated by hand.
  - *Cons*: might be broken easily, can be used multiple times.
- **Certificate codes**: I have a list of codes in two databases, one on the server and one on my phone. Every time a receipt is printed, one of these is printed in it and set as "used" into the database. On my phone, I do the same: I check if the code is in the database and hasn't been used yet, then set as "used" in the database.

  - *Pros*: doesn't allow for multiple uses of the same code.
  - *Cons*: it's extremely easy to fake a receipt, cannot be validated by hand.

Comment: If you use hashing, why can't you use the phone/client <-> database mechanism as well?

Comment: What do you want to validate, exactly? The fact that a certain document was produced by unmodified software made by yourself, running on unmodified hardware made by a no-name company, and was not tampered with since then? It makes no sense to tamper with signed recipes if I can take your signing engine out and make it sign whatever I want.

Answer (score 2):

**This sounds like a classic use case for an [Hash-based message authentication code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code) (HMAC) algorithm.**  Since your idea of "*by hand*" is "*using a smartphone*", not "*with pecil, paper, and mind*", you can compute the hash and print it on the receipt, and then validate it on the phone or the back-end server.

Answer (score -1):

The "missing point" is to use more systems at once so that, together, they work in the needed way. In this case, we can use HMAC for authenticating the message and a list of "certificate codes" to make sure one doesn't use the same receipt over and over.
Another idea might also be to hash the time when the receipt is outputted to the client and print it on the receipt. When someone shows you the code on the receipt, you make sure that hash hasn't been used yet and that it's valid (i.e. the message produces that hash), then you add it to the list of "used hashes".

Thanks to @RossPatterson for suggesting HMAC.